# Are git commits in gitlab api guaranteed to be sorted?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/commits.html#list-repository-commits simply states that `Get a list of repository commits in a project.`. Are those commits guaranteed to be sorted? Or in other words, can I use `page=1, per_page=1` to get just the newest commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `/projects/:id/repository/commits?page=1&per_page=1` gives the newest commit of the default branch. Use `ref_name` parameters to get commits from a different branch.